# User Input validation routine behaves strange

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small question regarding user input validation using JavaScript.

The following is the code that I wrote. It's working when this code does not have the 2nd validation. 
When I include the 2nd validation, even the first validation does not work.

Forget about that www.bbc.co.uk that I mentioned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function validateForm() {
    /* first validation */
    var eml = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (eml == null || eml == "") {
        alert("Email Address must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    /* second validation */
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9._-])+@[A-Za-z0-9.-])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if (reg.test(document.forms["myForm"]["emaill"].value) == false) {
        alert("Invalid Email - Reg Function");
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="www.bbc.co.uk" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more than just typo issues with your code. I semi-rewrote your function and here is a brief explanation on what I did.

Before, you were returning `false` twice, but never returning `true`. For `onSubmit()` to work, you have to return one of the two. You should create a `flag` variable and set it initially to `false`. Once all the criteria have been met for validation, then set it to true. At the end of the function, `return flag`.

Secondly, you were trying to grab `email` by it's `id` to set `focus()` on it, even though it didn't have an `id` set. For that, just set the form element to a variable and then set the elements value to a different variable so during the course of the function you have access to both (`eml` and `emlVal`)

Thirdly, your regex was invalid. The regex shown here was pulled from here:
[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Also, you should think twice about using it as that regex may not be RFC compliant:
[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Fourthly, email was being grabbed incorrectly from the `DOM`. You misspelled `email` in one portion of the code. To grab the element you need `var eml = document.myForm.email`. This will give you the `email` input element and then you can grab it's value with `eml.value`.

Lastly, unless I forgot something, the logic on the initial `if...else` should be `&& (and)` not an `|| (or)`

```
function validateForm() {
    var flag = false;
    /* first validation */
    var eml = document.myForm.email;
    var emlVal = eml.value;
    if (emlVal !== null && emlVal !== "") {
        var reg =/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if (!reg.test(emlVal)) {
            alert("Invalid Email - Reg Function");
            eml.focus();
        }
        else {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Email is required");
    }
    return flag;

    /* second validation */
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFgrR/1/)

Comment: Hi Christopher, Really appreciate your detailed explanation. Thanks a lot. Your explanation really helped me a lot since I am new to web development. I just moved into web development from IBM iSeries. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled "email" in this line:

```
if (reg.test(document.forms["myForm"]["emaill"].value) == false)
```

There's no reason to re-fetch the value from the DOM anyway; you already did that earlier in the function.

```
if (!reg.test(eml))
```

is enough.  It's generally a bad idea to compare explicitly to boolean constants. It's not necessarily wrong, but it's rarely necessary and it can cause strange things to happen if you're not used to the language.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: correct `emaill` to `email`.